# One site for multiple clients

Tags: laravel, web

All my clients will use the same website, however each customer will have their settings like colors, phones, emails etc.

I'm having doubts about this, if anyone can give me a sense of the best way to do this.

Note: Behind the site there is my backend in Laravel which is on my server.

Answer (score 0):

You can create user_details table to specify your clients base on their customization. You can study Laravel [Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships). To create relationship on your Users and UserDetails.